# Is it possible to distinguish which database type I am loading in springboot? (Oracle vs Azure SQL)

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, azure-sql-database

I am trying to find out how I can tell if I am loading Oracle or Azure SQL from bean initialization. Currently, I have to decide which database to load in my helm chart, either Oracle or Azure SQL. Then, I need to tell which xml file to load because the query syntax is little different. I was wondering if there is anyway to do this without using hardcoded value. This is my database bean config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ProjectDataSourceConfig {

    public static final String DB_TX_MANAGER = "";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.project")
    public DataSourceProperties projectDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource projectDataSource() {
        return projectDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(ComboPooledDataSource.class).build();
    }

   
    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate projectJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(projectDataSource());
    }

    @Bean(name = DB_TX_MANAGER)
    public DataSourceTransactionManager projectDbtransactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(projectDataSource());
    }
}
```

If this is possible, I also need to load different xml query files based on which database I am loading. For example, if I am loading Oracle, I want my repository to use oracle.xml file. Here is my current repository class: (I am currently using oracle)

```
@Configuration
@Import(ProjectDataSourceConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:event-sql-oracle.xml")
public class eEventRepositoryConfig {

    @Value("${EventRepository.insertEvent}")
    private String insertEvent;

    @Bean
    public EventRepository<Event> eventRepository(final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new EventRepository(jdbcTemplate, insertEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can possibly tell in the bean creation, but I can use .properties or helm chart to indicate db type.

```
env:
    db.type=oracle
```

and then use this for placeholder in the `@PropertySource` like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(ProjectDataSourceConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:event-sql-${db.type}.xml")
public class eEventRepositoryConfig {
```

I would have to change `db.type` as I am changing the server type in my configuration though.